# Compiling wxWidgets from command line

Tags: c++, command-line, wxwidgets

I want to compile the `wxWidgets v3.0.0` from `visual C++ 2010` command line, and I want to use `/MT` option which responsible for the C Runtime Library. and the following is what I have done:

```
nmake /MT -f makefile.vc BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=0 SHARED=0 UNICODE=1
```

But there is an error in the previous command `nmake fatal error u1065 invalid option 'M`, because this `/MT`. Note that `/MT`, `/MD`, etc are options in the compiler.

Now, how can I write the correct command that can control in use C runtime Library (`Static` or `Dynamic`)?

**Screenshot for the target option in the IDE.**
[image]

Comment: *there is an error* — I have an issue with this statement.

Comment: @n.m.: What's the problem in this statement! ?

Comment: Don't tell there's an error without telling *what* error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `RUNTIME_LIBS`, documented in `build\msw\config.vc` file, make option which can be used to select the kind of CRT to use. In your case you want to add `RUNTIME_LIBS=static` to your make command line. I.e. the full command becomes

```
nmake /f makefile.vc BUILD=release RUNTIME_LIBS=static
```

(`MONOLITHIC`, `SHARED` and `UNICODE` values you use are the defaults anyhow, so you can just as well omit them).

Comment: Yes, that is what I want exactly.

Comment: Is `SHARED` mean (static or dynamic) for wxWidgets lib, and `RUNTIME_LIBS` mean (static or dynamic) for c runtime. Am I on the right ?

Comment: Yes, see `config.vc` for the description.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have read the `config.vc` file, and there's something I did not understand. what is the difference between `DEBUG_RUNTIME_LIBS` and `RUNTIME_LIBS` options ?

Comment: `DEBUG_RUNTIME_LIBS` chooses between `/MD` and `/MDd` or `/MT` and `/MTd` while `RUNTIME_LIBS` chooses between `/MD` and `/MT`.

Answer (score 1):

`nmake` does not accept the same options your compiler accepts. It just doesn't work this way. You control the compiler and other programs invoked by `nmake` by creating and editing *makefiles*. You can find one such makefile in the list of command line arguments, it's the one after `-f`.

If you want to use a tool from the `make` family you *must* try to read and understand at least a basic `make` tutorial. I will not attempt to explain `make` from scratch here.

If your makefile is not too complex you might be able to figure out the required changes on your own, but I highly recommend reading a basic `make` or `nmake` tutorial anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but Mr `VZ.` answer is what I want exactly.